# ProgrammingError: column specified more than once

Tags: django, django-models

I'm attempting to run 'syncdb -all' in my django project, having just added this model.

However I'm getting this error message:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "target_content_type_id" specified more than once
```

Why is this happening when 'target_content_type_id' is not repeated and not in any other models?

```
class Action(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    verb = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    action_object_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, related_name='action_object', blank=True, null=True
    )
    action_object_object_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=500, blank=True, null=True
    )
    action_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(
        'action_object_content_type', 'action_object_object_id'
    )
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, related_name='target', blank=True, null=True
    )
    target_content_type_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=500, blank=True, null=True
    )
    target = generic.GenericForeignKey(
        'target_content_type', 'target_content_type_id'
    )

    public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a `ForeignKey` field, Behind the scenes, Django appends `"_id"` to the field name to create its database column name.

In this case, your field `target_content_type` which is a `ForeignKey`, would correspond to the database column `target_content_type_id`, which is conflicting with your charfield.

Rename your `target_content_type_id` to something else like `target_content_type_object_id` or something unique.

Here is the [documentation of `ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) and more [specifically on `Database Representation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)